# Implementing your own printf function in C. How do I implement pointers %p?

Tags: c, pointers

Working on a project with a friend, and we have to create our own printf function in C, we managed to print : c, s,d, etc.. (see code below). But Don't know how to print pointers.

What are the steps necessary to print pointers, what is needed to be able to receive a %p input from my printf function and print to the console the address, how do I deal with this.

I shared with you this screenshot to see what my teacher wants from me.
[image]

````
int ft_putchar(int c) {
    char a[1];
    a[0] = (char)c;
    return write(0, a, 1);
}

static int ft_printf_aux(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len);

static int ft_print_c(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    int c = va_arg(ap, int);
    ft_putchar(c);
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len + 1);
}

static int ft_putnum(unsigned long long n, unsigned int base, const char *digits) {
    int res = 1;
    if (n >= base)
        res += ft_putnum(n / base, base, digits);
    ft_putchar(digits[n % base]);
    return res;
}

static int ft_print_d(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    int n = va_arg(ap, int);
    unsigned long long u;
    if (n < 0) {
        ft_putchar('-');
        len++;
        u = -(unsigned)n;
    } else {
        u = n;
    }
    len += ft_putnum(u, 10, "0123456789");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_o(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 8, "01234567");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_u(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 10, "0123456789");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_x(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 16, "0123456789abcdef");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_X(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 16, "0123456789ABCDEF");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_s(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    const char *s = va_arg(ap, const char *);
    if (s == NULL) {
        s = "(null)";
    }
    while (*s) {
        ft_putchar(*s++);
        len++;
    }
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

typedef int (*ft_print_dispatch_f)(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len);

static ft_print_dispatch_f const ft_print_dispatch[256] = {
    ['c'] = ft_print_c,
    ['d'] = ft_print_d,
    ['i'] = ft_print_d,
    ['o'] = ft_print_o,
    ['u'] = ft_print_u,
    ['x'] = ft_print_x,
    ['X'] = ft_print_X,
    ['s'] = ft_print_s,
};

static int ft_printf_aux(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    int c;

    while (*fmt) {
        c = (unsigned char)*fmt++;
        if (c != '%') {
            ft_putchar(c);
            len++;
        } else {
            c = (unsigned char)*fmt++;
            if (ft_print_dispatch[c] == NULL) {
                if (c == '\0')
                    break;
                ft_putchar(c);
                len++;
            } else {
                return ft_print_dispatch[c](fmt, ap, len);
            }
        }
    }
    return len;
}

int ft_vprintf(const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, 0);
}

int ft_printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int n;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, 0);
    va_end(ap);
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    ft_printf("Hello word\n");
    ft_printf("%cello %s\n", 'H', "word");
    ft_printf("%d == 0%o == 0x%x == 0x%X\n", 1, 1, 1, 1);
    ft_printf("%d == 0%o == 0x%x == 0x%X\n", 123, 123, 123, 123);
    ft_printf("%d == 0%o == 0x%x == 0x%X\n", 0xdead, 0xdead, 0xdead, 0xdead);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Call `ft_print_x` for each byte (as unsigned). Might have to experiment with the order if it comes out backwards

Comment: There isn't even an attempt to print a pointer. What is the pointer size on your platform? If it's 32 bit just print it as %x. If it's 64 bits it's hardly more complicated.

Comment: "Can you help?" is not considered a question on StackOverflow. Please describe what has you stuck. Did you try to treat the pointer like a number? How did that fail? What was the result? In which way does it differ from the desired result?

Comment: Just a hint: Use a `union` of a pointer and an `unsigned char` array of appropriate size. Print the array's elements.

Comment: From the picture I saw that a pointer is 64 bits on your platform. Printing a pointer is therefore more or less equivalent to printing an `unsigned long long`. Your code has everything to do that, just copy/paste one of your `ft_print_*` functions and modify it accordingly.

Comment: @thebusybee That would require taking endianess into account.

Comment: The [musl-libc](http://musl.libc.org/) library is open source and has an implementation of `printf`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I suppose it's an exercise.

Comment: Elvandil, for an eye to the future, rather than `ft_putnum(unsigned long long n, ...` consider `ft_putnum(uintmax_t n`.  Use the widest integer type.

Answer (score 2):

`"%p"` matches a `void *`, not just any pointer.

```
const void *ptr = va_arg(ap, void *);
```

Convert to an integer with `(u)intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`

```
uintptr_t uptr = (uintptr_t) ptr;
```

Now print the integer as you like.  Format for pointers is an implementation detail.

```
// Sample
pad_width = (sizeof uptr * CHAR_BIT + 3)/4;
len += ft_putnum_with_padding(uptr, 16, "0123456789ABCDEF", pad_width);
```